# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Estoy construyendo un método en el `backend` para borrar archivos en una base de datos MongoDB usando Mongoose.

Adjunto el código que me funciona bien en las pruebas que hago en Postman, pero sólo en la primera llamada que hago al método, pues si intento borrar otro archivo me despliega el error que señalo en mi pregunta.

Revisé las respuestas a preguntas similares, pero no consigo dar con la manera de solucionarlo. Agradeceré la ayuda que me puedan dar.

El código:

```
deleteFile: function(req, res) {

    // Sacar el id del proyecto y del archivo a borrar
    var projectId = req.params.projectId;
    var imgId = req.params.imgId;

    // Buscar el proyecto sobre el que queremos actuar
    Project.findById(projectId, (err, project) => {

        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: "Error en la petición del projecto para capturar su ID"
            });
        }
        if (!project) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: "No existe el projecto"
            });
        }
        // Seleccionar el subdocumento (imagen o archivo)
        //var imageFile = project.image.id(imageId);
        var imageFile = project.image.id(imgId);
        // Borrar el subdocumento
        if (imageFile) {
            imageFile.remove();

            // Guardar el proyecto
            project.save((err) => {

                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send({
                        status: 'eror',
                        message: 'Error al guardar imágenes'

                    });
                }
                // devolver una respuesta
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    project

                });

            });

            // Devolver un resultado

            return res.status(200).send({
                message: "Se borró el archivo/imagen en la base de datos",

            });


        } else {
            return res.status(404).send({
                message: "No existe el archivo/imagen que se quiere borrar"
            });
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Como te responden, el problema es que tienes 2 sentencias con `return res.status(200) ...` para el mismo middleware, lo cual no es correcto. De hecho, la sentencia más anidada, al ser ejecutada dentro de una función `callback`, se ejecuta después de la sentencia donde pones el mensaje: `'Se borró el archivo ...'`. Como te sugieren en la respuesta, la solución es eliminar dicha sentencia return de tu lógica. Saludos

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, verdaderamente me han ayudado a salir de este problema

Comment: Debes estar haciendo un return status pero como un **callback** en alguna parte que esta devolviendo una respuesta y no te das cuenta porque no lo estas controlando y estas haciendo otro return despues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soy angloparlante, pero intento ayudarlo a través de una aplicación de traducción.

Eliminar este código:

```
        return res.status(200).send({
            message: "Se borró el archivo/imagen en la base de datos",

        });
```

Ya está enviando una respuesta en `project.save ()`, por lo que esta es una respuesta duplicada que conduce al error que ve.

Comment: Thank you friend, thank you for taking the time to respond and find a way to do it by removing the language barrier. I solved the problem!! (I also use a translation app)